# Drawables not changing after being replaced with others in the folders

Tags: android, image, drawable

I've created a new theme set for an app of mine, and decided I didn't need the old one anymore.
So, I copied my new image files over the old ones, replacing all of them. I did this for all of my drawables folders.
I then recreated `R.java` just in case, and rebuild my application.

For some reason, it's picking up the old images and displaying those.
Alright, I thought, must be something in the memory / cache. I'll just wipe my emulator image and try again.

After doing so, the app still used the old pictures. I thought I must have made a mistake and checked the images in Eclipse, but it showed the new images there. 
I then took drastic matters and deleted the drawables folders. Ofcourse this caused my project to freak out so I quickly added the desired new pictures and rebuild the project. No errors showed up, and all pictures appeared changed in Eclipse.

But when running the app, the old pictures still showed. Except in some parts of the app. Out of 70 or so pictures that I used, only 2 were now displaying the new version. All the other ones are still showing the old pictures.

What can be going on here? I tried restarting my emulator, resfreshing the project, creating a new project using the old one as the source, restarting my phone, wiping all app data before installing the app, deleting all images and replacing them with the new ones, but nothing seems to work.

How can an app that contains new images, thats being run on a completely fresh emulator, still display images that have been deleted at least an hour earlier?

Comment: Did you refresh eclipse? (you can select your res-folder in eclipse and press f5)

Comment: Forgot to add that to the list, but yes I did. That was the first thing I did. I tried all the options that Eclipse can throw at you in terms of refreshing/fixing/building projects. Nothing seems to change the outcome even though the GUI builder shows the new pics for instance.

Comment: I assume you also tried a different emulator, just in case? or on a real device?

Comment: Yep, tried it on my phone, same result. Uninstalled the app, restarted the phone, same result. Completely new emulator? You guessed it, same result.  I'm kind of running out of options.  The folders show the correct images, Eclipse shows the correct images, but still it manages to grab not one, not two, but over 70 non-existant images. I just may have discovered how to use ghost-data.

Comment: That's really odd. Tried wiping your bin-folder?

Comment: Just tried that, resulted in my project going completely haywire for a while, deleting imports all over the place but once that was fixed it worked! Thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wipe your **bin-folder** to remove old compiled data.

Comment: If there is nothing in your bin folder then you can try wiping your 'gen' folder too.

Comment: if you're not comfortable with wiping the whole bin folder, try the 'resources.ap_' file - worked for me!

Comment: I simply deleted the `bin/` folder and this solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR: check your other drawable-xxxdpi folders for old versions too!**

I had this same problem, and none of the solutions here helped. It was driving me crazy.

I had replaced res/drawable-hdpi/file.jpg with file.png. It was a different extension and had different content. Eclipse was seeing the new version, but no amount of cleaning/refreshing, uninstalling the app or manually deleting bin/gen folders made the device see the new version.

Then I realized that I had other versions in:

- res/drawable-ldpi/file.jpg
- res/drawable-mdpi/file.jpg
- res/drawable-xhdpi/file.jpg

Once I replaced those versions with resized versions of file.png, then a simple re-run of the app fixed the issue. It seems like the Android resource compiler saw a "jpg" version of the file first in another of the drawable folders, then ignored the subsequent "png" version in drawable-hdpi. Even though the device it was running on was hdpi, the drawable was coming out of another dpi folder.

Answer (score 1):

If checking other Drawable folders for old versions and wiping your bin and gen folders didn't work.

Look for: `setImageResource(R.drawable.YourPNG)` in your code that might override the drawable configured in xml from: res/layout/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio:**
If `Clean` and `Build` doesn´t work try with

Go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

or  `File` > `Synchronize`

both worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution is to **uninstall the app from your emulator** *then reinstall by running it again from Android Studio.* (This will force everything to update)

This is always a weird problem but I figured this out by deleting the older images from my pc, yet the older image would still show up on the app (which is impossible). So I figured the problem was with the emulator. (since the emulator has its own storage)

If filepath and file names stay the same I guess Android doesn't update your app, even though the new image is a different size. Weird.