# Changed splash.png image but it doesn't change in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, splash-screen

I'm just wrangling with Eclipse and updated the splash.9.png image in the res/ folder, but when test-running the app on my phone (USB-connected) it's still showing the old splash screen image.

Do I need to clear caches somewhere in Eclipse? Running Eclipse Juno for mobile developers.

Thank you!

Comment: by res you mean res/drawable, right? are you sure also that your resource selectors are correct (you old splash may be in a drawable-hdpi folder as well, for instance.) btw, splash screens are evil.

Comment: Did you refresh the project after updating the image? In case you replaced the old png with the new one from outside Eclipse, you should select the project's root item in the Project Explorer and then hit F5 (or right-click and hit the Refresh option).

Comment: As suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431605/drawables-not-changing-after-being-replaced-with-others-in-the-folders try clearing your bin-folder.

Comment: try to restart your eclipse and unistall the app from emulator  then  run again .. also clear data when unistalling the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have the same problem on Helios but haven't had it yet on Juno, it seems to update automatically when I next save a change.

Try moving the image to a different directory, make a change in Eclipse and save so it registers the lack of the drawable and then move the updated image back. That's how I used to fix it in Helios, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for now! Also clearing the bin/ folder. Hope I won't have to do everytime I make changes to the app.

Comment: Had to delete the bin folder, uninstalling the app didn't work.