# Replaced drawable not changing

Tags: android, android-drawable

I replaced one of my drawable images with a different image (and different color), but the drawable isn't changing in the app.

I saw a similar question like this:

[Drawables not changing after being replaced with others in the folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431605/drawables-not-changing-after-being-replaced-with-others-in-the-folders)

But the answers didn't help me. I can't find a "bin" folder within my Android Studio project. I also replaced the drawable in each of the drawable folders.

Comment: There are many suggestions in the question you linked, most importantly: check if you have any old images left (for example if you changed the file extension) and make sure you perform a clean rebuild (this is the "delete the `bin` folder" thing -- make sure all temporary build files are cleared, either from your IDE or via `ant clean`).

Comment: how are you accesing the files? post some code

Comment: I had logo_round which I wanted to replace. I created a new file with name test.png, saved the image in all folders. Renamed all layouts with a new name. Restarted, invalidated, clean build but still after generating build I see old image. Did you find any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh your project!

`Refresh` and `build your project` again!, this will recreate the content inside the `/bin` folder.

**Eclipse:** 
press <kbd>f5</kbd>

You don´t need to change the name of your resources, just check if all the drawables were changed in all `/drawable` folders.

**Android Studio**:

Go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

OR 
`File` > `Synchronize`

**update:**
Here you can find more info about this issue:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/android-studio-drawable-files-doesnt-change-after-replacing

Comment: I tried the following in Android Studio: `Invalidate Caches / Restart`, `Rebuild Project`, `Clean Project`. It's still showing the old image.

Comment: do you have the same image for different densities, check all your drawable folders.

Comment: Yes, I changed the image in each drawable folder.

Comment: then try with File > Invalidate Caches / Restart OR File > Synchronize

Comment: that takes 5 hours though, surely there's a simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

You can find the bin folder in the Windows Explorer (or Finder, or the Linux one).

You must delete the file from there, or do a clean in the project (I don't know how on Android Studio) that would delete that folder.

If doing this don't work, change the name of your drawable to a new one and use it, if the old name is still usable this means that your R class are not being regenerated ( and a cause for this would be some error in any XML in the res folder, or a invalid drawable)

Comment: Uh...where in the Windows Explorer specifically?

Comment: Your project path/bin

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps-

Try these steps, it worked for me in the first try.

```
Close Android Studio
Go to the location where your project is saved (ex.: C:\Users...\Documents\AndroidStudio\FunFacts)
Go all the way until you get to the "res" folder (FunFacts\app\src\main\res)
Unzip the icon file that you downloaded
Enter each drawable folder and replace the old icon with the unziped icon
Open AndroidStudio
```

Note-If you still not succeed the 
 try renaming the files and adding them back again?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, check it out!

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/android-studio-drawable-files-doesnt-change-after-replacing