# How to refresh image beside line number in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-studio-2.1

I am using Android Studio version 2.1.1 for developing an android application and I recently found something which I feel is a bug.

I like a feature that is, when I write code containing resources (ex, R.drawable.~~~), resource images are shown beside line number.

This is as well present in Android Studio versions 1.x.x

Recently I found that some images aren't getting displayed.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to clean, invalidate cache and restart Android Studio like this:

1- go to android studio’s menu bar Build > Rebuild Project

2- go to android studio’s menu bar Build > Clean Project

3- got to android studio’s menu bar File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

If this doesn't work, see [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/android-studio-drawable-files-doesnt-change-after-replacing) for more information

Hope this helps

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431605/drawables-not-changing-after-being-replaced-with-others-in-the-folders), did you try to delete your bin folder to delete previously compiled data? You can also try File -> Synchronize.

Comment: I don't have bin folder... where is it?

Comment: Sorry, the bin folder would be with Eclipse. My bad. Did you try the synchronization solution?